# Migrating from Webrat to Capybara...unsuccessfully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Hoping someone might see what I've overlooked...

I'm trying to get Capybara working in a small existing application...and I'm not having any luck.

Gemfile:

```
  group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    # gem 'webrat'
    gem 'capybara', :git => 'git://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git'
  end
  ...
```

Similar specs in two places are failing for different reasons. Not sure why?

**spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do

  describe "GET 'about'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      # get 'about'                         #worked w/ webrat
      # response.should be_success          #worked w/ webrat
      visit pages_about_path
      # page.should have_content('About Us') 
      page.html.should match(/About/i)
    end

    it "should have title" do
      # get 'about'                         #webrat
      # response.should have_selector("title", :content => "About Us") #webrat
      visit pages_about_path                
      page.should have_selector("title")    
    end
  end  
end
```

**Failures:**
*(may be pulling in some generic page as doctype in browser is `"<!DOCTYPE html>"`)*

```
  1) PagesController GET 'about' should be successful
     Failure/Error: page.html.should match(/About/i)
       expected "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n\n" to match /About/i
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) PagesController GET 'about' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: page.should have_selector("title") 
       expected css "title" to return something
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**spec/views/pages/about.html.haml_spec.rb:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "pages/about.html.haml" do
  it "renders attributes in <p>" do
    # render #webrat
    # rendered.should match(/About/) #webrat
    visit pages_about_path
    page.should have_content("About Us")
  end

  it "should have the right heading" do  
    # render #webrat
    # rendered.should have_selector("h2", :content => "About Us") #webrat
    visit pages_about_path
    page.should have_selector("h2")
  end
end
```

**Failures:**

```
  1) pages/about.html.haml renders attributes in <p>
     Failure/Error: visit pages_about_path
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x00000101dc2970>
     # ./spec/views/pages/about.html.haml_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) pages/about.html.haml should have the right heading
     Failure/Error: visit pages_about_path
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x000001034b1d98>
     # ./spec/views/pages/about.html.haml_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Please mark nigelr (or whomever you think deserves it) as the accepted answer for others who might have this problem and as common courtesy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just had the same issue and found that capybara needs:

```
response.body.should have_selector("title")
```

webrat does not need the .body

also, make sure you are rendering views eg:.

```
describe PagesController do
  render_views
```

Comment: This is the answer. Also, if you are coming from railstutorial.org, I believe you also need to change :content => "whatever" to :title => "whatever". Otherwise it passes regardless of the content.

Comment: I think yakiimo means that `have_selector("title", :content => "Home")` becomes `have_selector("title", :text => "Home")`. I also found that `have_selector("a", :href => "/users?page=2", :content => "Next")` changes to `have_link("Next", :href => "/users?page=2")`. I'm finding the before-and-after examples in this blog post helpful:  [Migrating from Webrat to Capybara](http://zadasnotes.blogspot.com/2011/08/migrating-from-webrat-to-capybara.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should include capybara DSL in your test file :

```
require 'spec_helper'

    describe PagesController do

    include Capybara::DSL

      describe "GET 'about'" do
        it "should be successful" do 
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't fix all your problems, but Instead of:

```
page.html.should match(/About/i)
```

try:

```
page.should match(/About/i)
```

(you might not even need *page*).

Also, check that you have Capybara set to use CSS queries in env.rb (it defaults to XPath).

Comment: Dropping the 'html.' didn't work. Also, Capybara's read me states: "Capybara does not try to guess what kind of selector you are going to give it, and will **always use CSS by default**. If you want to use XPath, you’ll need to do..."  Seeing error "**undefined method `visit'**" makes me think Capybara isn't installed or referenced correctly...but not sure how to confirm!?!

Comment: Hmm, the env.rb Cucumber generates says "Capybara defaults to XPath selectors rather than Webrat's default of CSS3". But yeah, it sounds like it's not picking up Capybara. Have you tried running through Bundler? bundle exec cucumber

Comment: not using Cucumber...don't really want to... is that maybe the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your `spec_helper.rb` file has the following at the top:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

I had a similar issue as yours (i.e., `undefined method 'visit'`) and popping those lines solved the issue.